# Suggested Edit status is showing rejected but it shows pending review in the review section

Tags: discussion, bug, editing

I [suggested an edit](https://music.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/39338) on [this post](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/66394/45896).

This post was vandalized by the original poster and picked by SmokeDetector in [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42633714#42633714). I used the source of [previous version](https://music.stackexchange.com/revisions/66394/1) to restore it with a minor spelling correction.

A few minutes later, a moderator rolled it back to previous version which should reject my edit automatically but it is still showing pending, though it shows rejected in [my activity tab](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/45896/a-j?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

Why is it showing like this? Is this a bug?